# MQRC Resource problem in WebSphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

This is in Cluster Environment. Queue Manager lost its identity in cluster and it is unable to connect to other servers. All channels to repository and others were retrying state.

CPU usage is optimal in this server. This is a UNIX box.

When I checked the logs below is it,

> AMQ9532: Program cannot set queue
>   attributes.
>
> EXPLANATION: The attempt to set the
>   attributes of queue
>   'SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.QUEUE' on
>   queue manager 'QMGR.SERVER6A' failed
>   with reason code 2102.
>
> ACTION: Ensure
>   that the queue is available and retry
>   the operation.
>
> ----- amqrmssa.c : 690 --------------------------------------------------------
>   AMQ9999: Channel program ended
>   abnormally.
>
> EXPLANATION: Channel program
>   'Channel.Coord00' ended abnormally.
>
> ACTION: Look at previous error
>   messages for channel program
>   'Channel.Coord00' in the error files to
>   determine the cause of the failure.
>
> ----- amqrccca.c : 883 --------------------------------------------------------
>   03/06/11  08:24:26 AMQ9544: Messages
>   not put to destination queue.
>
> EXPLANATION: During the processing of
>   channel 'Channel.Server6A' one or more
>   messages could not be put to the
>   destination queue and attempts were
>   made to put them to a dead-letter
>   queue.  The location of the queue is
>   1, where 1 is the local dead-letter
>   queue and 2 is the remote dead-letter
>   queue.
>
> ACTION: Examine the contents of
>   the dead-letter queue.  Each message
>   is contained in a structure that
>   describes why the message was put to
>   the queue, and to where it was
>   originally addressed. Also look at
>   previous error messages to see if the
>   attempt to put messages to a
>   dead-letter queue failed. The program
>   identifier (PID) of the processing
>   program was '1372200'.
>
> ----- amqrmrca.c : 1318 -------------------------------------------------------

Then I did recycled the queue manager it is now fine?

My question here is how did the MQ resource problem occurr? CPU usage of this server is not more than 15%. Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

There are three different and unrelated problems shown in the log.

---

> AMQ9532: Program cannot set queue
>   attributes.
>
> EXPLANATION: The attempt to set the
>   attributes of queue
>   'SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.QUEUE' on
>   queue manager 'QMGR.SERVER6A' failed
>   with reason code 2102.

The 2102 is MQRC_RESOURCE_PROBLEM and presumably the resource issue referred to in the posting.  The 2102 can be any kind of scarce resource, including semaphores, user processes, queue handles, etc.  Since the QMgr was attempting to set an attribute of the queue, it would have already had a thread instantiated but it would have required additional queue handles.  When something like this occurs, use your admin tool (WMQ Explorer, mqmon or one of the many 3rd party tools) to look into the number of open queue handles, open channels, etc.  Note that for a resource error, it will be necessary to maintain an open connection to the QMgr or else the tool will be unable to make a new connection when the resource shortage occurs.

---

> AMQ9999: Channel program ended
>   abnormally.
>
> EXPLANATION: Channel program
>   'Channel.Coord00' ended abnormally.
>
> ACTION: Look at previous error
>   messages for channel program
>   'C00.US.MP00' in the error files to
>   determine the cause of the failure.

This error appears to actually be two different errors since it references two different channels.  One of these appears to be an outbound cluster channel and the other appears to be a point-to-point channel.  Neither channel mentioned in this error are associated with the first and last error message.

---

> 03/06/11 08:24:26 AMQ9544: Messages
>   not put to destination queue.
>
> EXPLANATION: During the processing of
>   channel 'Channel.Server6A' one or more
>   messages could not be put to the
>   destination queue and attempts were
>   made to put them to a dead-letter
>   queue. The location of the queue is 1,
>   where 1 is the local dead-letter queue
>   and 2 is the remote dead-letter queue.
>
> ACTION: Examine the contents of the
>   dead-letter queue. Each message is
>   contained in a structure that
>   describes why the message was put to
>   the queue, and to where it was
>   originally addressed. Also look at
>   previous error messages to see if the
>   attempt to put messages to a
>   dead-letter queue failed. The program
>   identifier (PID) of the processing
>   program was '1372200'.

The last error appears to be an inbound cluster channel.  Since the first error was trying to set attributes of the cluster transmit queue, it could only have been associated with an outbound channel.  Therefore the first and last error messages are unrelated.  This error message appears to show an inbound message that was destined for a queue and that queue was full, PUT-disabled, or otherwise unable to accept the message.  The message was therefore routed to the dead letter queue.

---

For the resource error, I would suggest reviewing the performance report appropriate to your platform.  Go to the [SupportPacs page](http://bit.ly/SupportPacs) and look for those SupportPacs named MP* and then look for the one for your platform.  The Performance Reports give you specific tuning advice.

You may also want to review the *[Problem Determination](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa14820_.htm)* chapter in the System Administration manual for additional advice on how to identify resource issues.

The *[WebSphere MQ cluster design and operation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0912_mismes/0912_mismes.html)* article in the developerWorks Mission:Messaging series has specific advice about keeping clusters healthy.

Last but not least, the [WebSphere MQ MustGather](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg21229861) page has sections on troubleshooting for all major platforms and categorized by problem area.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the MAXMSGL to 100 MB in IBMMQ,
(Reason code-2102 - MQRC_RESOURCE_PROBLEM) after setting the MAXMSGL to 100 mb

Category: IBM WebSphere MQ

If you are receiving error Reason code:2102 - MQRC_RESOURCE_PROBLEM, then try

Queue manager->properties->Extended->Increase Log->Log primary files and Log->Log secondary files->value to 20

Comment: As mentioned in the answer posted 9 years ago when this question was written, the 2102 can be caused by any number of resource issues: memory, disk space, as you mention transaction log.  I see nothing in the question about increasing MAXMSGL to 100MB, so this seems like a odd detail to provide in your answer.  Maybe you can explain some more in your answer why you think this will fix the OP (original posters) question?